# Which regular expression or pattern should be used to grab following contents from the text file?

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I need to split text starting from "9=DEXTER" upto the next "9=DEXTER". How to write pattern regex for it in java. using end of the line doesnt works since some phrase merged with the previouse phrase line.

```
9=DEXTER.1.19=14161035=X49=PARFX56=c3_user134=847152=20130408-22:27:59.606262=aquru2D00000016268=1618279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27426.89271=01023=35336=3346=0273=22:27:22.935279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27386.32271=460000001023=489336=3346=1273=22:27:22.9358722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27388.25271=01023=472336=3346=0273=22:27:22.935279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27429.08271=440000001023=7336=3346=1273=22:27:22.9358722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27410.08271=440000001023=233336=3346=1273=22:27:22.9368722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27375.1271=01023=635336=3346=0273=22:27:23.013279=0269=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27429.01271=01023=9336=3346=0273=22:27:23.015279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27377.79271=410000001023=599336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0158722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27372.1271=01023=679336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27363.78271=480000001023=799336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27403.94271=01023=299336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27418.77271=440000001023=119336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27379.15271=01023=587336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27396.59271=410000001023=377336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27415.88271=470000001023=153336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.14271=460000001023=625336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27410.47271=950000001023=234336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27402.08271=01023=323336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27366.49271=880000001023=762336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27374.05271=01023=658336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27411.14271=850000001023=225336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27396.3271=01023=384336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.61271=410000001023=743336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.69271=01023=618336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27384.88271=430000001023=514336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27409.38271=01023=245336=3346=0273=22:27:23.019279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27425.95271=460000001023=45336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0198722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27399.42271=01023=350336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27365.76271=470000001023=769336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27425.19271=01023=56336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27409.56271=480000001023=244336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27414.01271=01023=180336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27369.37271=440000001023=716336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27391.09271=480000001023=436336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27408.21271=410000001023=256336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27401.79271=01023=325336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27365.15271=420000001023=780336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27422.14271=01023=79336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27385.93271=400000001023=497336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27372.05271=460000001023=676336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27389.2271=01023=458336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27363.57271=01023=803336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27395.22271=440000001023=392336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27414.19271=01023=175336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27369.27271=440000001023=719336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27363.87271=01023=798336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.07271=470000001023=622336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.43271=01023=749336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27375.68271=440000001023=630336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27394.26271=01023=400336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27399.66271=450000001023=344336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27391.84271=01023=428336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.69271=430000001023=744336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27383.3271=01023=524336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27391.39271=470000001023=434336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.04271=01023=623336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27422.87271=440000001023=74336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27394.4271=01023=400336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27406.86271=400000001023=272336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27371.41271=01023=686336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27391.21271=420000001023=436336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27393.08271=01023=419336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27411.57271=440000001023=217336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27377.01271=01023=613336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27417.43271=460000001023=137336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27375.62271=01023=632336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27406.25271=480000001023=280336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27393.35271=450000001023=420336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27369.79271=01023=712336=3346=0273=22:27:23.020279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.1271=410000001023=754336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0208722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27428.03271=01023=22336=3346=0273=22:27:23.021279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27364.26271=470000001023=791336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27410.59271=01023=231336=3346=0273=22:27:23.021279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27409.68271=410000001023=242336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27368.55271=01023=732336=3346=0273=22:27:23.021279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27361.51271=470000001023=826336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27427.01271=01023=34336=3346=0273=22:27:23.021279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27373.46271=440000001023=663336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27373.24271=01023=667336=3346=0273=22:27:23.021279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27371.7271=470000001023=683336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27406.32271=870000001023=277336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0218722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27417.99271=01023=129336=3346=0273=22:27:23.030279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27424.26271=440000001023=63336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0308722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27408.47271=860000001023=251336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0308722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27385.26271=01023=508336=3346=0273=22:27:23.030279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27408.04271=430000001023=257336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0308722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27380.55271=440000001023=570336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0308722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27386.54271=01023=492336=3346=0273=22:27:23.030279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27407.53271=450000001023=265336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0308722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.93271=01023=739336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27389271=440000001023=468336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27417.4271=01023=137336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27378.95271=410000001023=591336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27414.13271=01023=175336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27402.32271=460000001023=319336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27363.29271=01023=807336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27387.36271=410000001023=486336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27365.83271=480000001023=770336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27388.41271=01023=476336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27422.92271=460000001023=73336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27381.24271=01023=554336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27372.87271=480000001023=672336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27411.83271=01023=211336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27380.18271=400000001023=578336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27418.84271=01023=118336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27418.56271=470000001023=122336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27402.22271=410000001023=322336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27415.2271=420000001023=162336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27380.62271=01023=568336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27394.53271=420000001023=403336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27363.07271=460000001023=810336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27371.91271=01023=683336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27403.21271=460000001023=314336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27366.15271=01023=767336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27404.62271=470000001023=299336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27428.68271=01023=13336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27421.68271=440000001023=84336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27383.64271=01023=528336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27406.89271=470000001023=273336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27390.24271=480000001023=459336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27426.55271=01023=38336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27397.13271=450000001023=377336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27421.39271=01023=86336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27387.24271=01023=493336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.8271=420000001023=619336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27414.34271=450000001023=173336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27421.22271=470000001023=88336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27379.57271=01023=587336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27365.44271=450000001023=782336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27427.86271=410000001023=24336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27374.74271=400000001023=650336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27393.64271=01023=419336=3346=0273=22:27:23.031279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27411.68271=480000001023=212336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0318722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27428.72271=01023=12336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27417.38271=480000001023=136336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27392.86271=01023=430336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27393.98271=01023=415336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27403.5271=440000001023=310336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27408.61271=01023=248336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27395.94271=1340000001023=392336=3346=3273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27421.93271=01023=78336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27394.16271=480000001023=412336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27373.42271=01023=668336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27376.74271=430000001023=619336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27385.8271=01023=505336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27386.07271=480000001023=502336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=1269=055=USD/JPY270=27370.71271=420000001023=702336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27375.48271=410000001023=638336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27367.54271=01023=749336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27397.96271=410000001023=372336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27387.13271=01023=494336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27369.34271=420000001023=723336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27397.22271=440000001023=377336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27414.57271=01023=168336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27417.1271=460000001023=139336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27418.39271=01023=121336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27379.95271=480000001023=582336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27362.45271=01023=821336=3346=0273=22:27:23.032279=0269=055=USD/JPY270=27415.43271=460000001023=157336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0328722=0279=2269=055=USD/JPY270=27381.68271=01023=5491023=197336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0698722=0279=2269=155=USD/JPY270=27611.88271=01023=450336=3346=0273=22:27:23.069279=1269=155=USD/JPY270=27647.01271=920000001023=28336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0698722=0279=2269=155=USD/JPY270=27627.33271=01023=270336=3346=0273=22:27:23.069279=0269=155=USD/JPY270=27589.8271=410000001023=732336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0698722=0279=2269=155=USD/JPY270=27605.53271=01023=538336=3346=0273=22:27:23.069279=0269=155=USD/JPY270=27594.08271=400000001023=681336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0698722=0279=0269=155=USD/JPY270=27590.08271=410000001023=729336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0698722=0279=2269=155=USD/JPY270=27610.17271=01023=475336=3346=0273=22:27:23.069279=0269=155=USD/JPY270=27592.31271=430000001023=706336=3346=1273=22:27:23.1868722=0279=2269=155=USD/JPY270=27605.46271=01023=552336=3346=0273=22:27:23.186279=0269=155=USD/JPY270=27594.22271=430000001023=685336=3346=1273=22:27:23.1868722=010=0259=DEXTER.1.19=14351935=X49=PARFX56=c3_user134=847252=20130408-22:27:59.607262=aquru2D00000017268=1642279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27379.21271=01023=613336=3346=0273=22:27:22.982279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27380.1271=480000001023=606336=3346=1273=22:27:22.9828722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27376.45271=410000001023=646336=3346=1273=22:27:22.9828722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27387.81271=01023=507336=3346=0273=22:27:23.016279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27362.9271=430000001023=820336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0168722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27395.77271=01023=422336=3346=0273=22:27:23.016279=1269=055=USD/MXN270=27416.59271=900000001023=148336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0168722=0279=1269=055=USD/MXN270=27402.53271=410000001023=342336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27421.47271=410000001023=91336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27362.04271=01023=831336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27381.51271=01023=590336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27400.8271=400000001023=362336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27409271=01023=256336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27403.23271=420000001023=336336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27407.45271=01023=272336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=1269=055=USD/MXN270=27419.1271=880000001023=120336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27412.67271=01023=198336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27402.01271=410000001023=348336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27392.64271=01023=461336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27413.07271=01023=196336=3346=0273=22:27:23.040279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27393.88271=420000001023=445336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0408722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27370.76271=01023=701336=3346=0273=22:27:23.047279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27414.74271=01023=174336=3346=0273=22:27:23.047279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27418.51271=410000001023=128336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0478722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27407.91271=01023=267336=3346=0273=22:27:23.047279=1269=055=USD/MXN270=27371.75271=850000001023=691336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0478722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27392.26271=01023=464336=3346=0273=22:27:23.047279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27379.5271=470000001023=606336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0478722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27372.2271=01023=685336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27382.86271=430000001023=566336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27388.84271=01023=495336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27427.92271=440000001023=22336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27394.39271=01023=438336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27413.33271=440000001023=194336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27428.59271=01023=9336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27399.7271=410000001023=375336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27362.95271=01023=815336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27362.65271=470000001023=820336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27387.39271=01023=510336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27370.5271=01023=702336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27421.64271=450000001023=91336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27379.76271=470000001023=604336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27384.65271=01023=533336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27393.78271=430000001023=449336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27427.43271=460000001023=26336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27367.2271=470000001023=759336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27364.08271=01023=797336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27370.92271=480000001023=702336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27363.19271=400000001023=813336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27363.46271=01023=810336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27407.56271=470000001023=272336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27393.97271=460000001023=448336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27403.04271=01023=337336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27413.94271=01023=188336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27428.66271=01023=8336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27406.51271=01023=282336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=2269=055=USD/MXN270=27368.62271=01023=741336=3346=0273=22:27:23.048279=1269=055=USD/MXN270=27403.45271=900000001023=331336=3346=2273=22:27:23.0488722=0279=0269=055=USD/MXN270=27387.94271=470000001023=505336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0488722=01023=590336=3346=0273=22:27:23.243279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27638.8271=470000001023=115336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2438722=0279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27632.43271=400000001023=189336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2438722=0279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27647.52271=430000001023=23336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2438722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27622.85271=01023=299336=3346=0273=22:27:23.243279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27624.18271=460000001023=274336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2438722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27610.29271=01023=465336=3346=0273=22:27:23.243279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27626.95271=440000001023=242336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2438722=0279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27648.18271=460000001023=12336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27621.89271=420000001023=316336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27628.57271=01023=229336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27636.79271=410000001023=142336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27637.38271=01023=133336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27602.75271=400000001023=565336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27620.37271=440000001023=338336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27630.68271=01023=209336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27636.13271=850000001023=150336=3346=2273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27610.2271=400000001023=468336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27624.31271=480000001023=271336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27605.29271=01023=532336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27601.37271=920000001023=583336=3346=2273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27635.6271=01023=158336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27601.6271=890000001023=579336=3346=2273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=2269=155=USD/MXN270=27602.71271=01023=565336=3346=0273=22:27:23.244279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27600.74271=430000001023=591336=3346=1273=22:27:23.2448722=0279=1269=155=USD/MXN270=27623.63271=400000001023=284336=3346=1273=22:27:23.3238722=0279=0269=155=USD/MXN270=27602.66271=400000001023=566336=3346=1273=22:27:23.3238722=010=012
132157:8473:OUT 20130408-22:27:59.611 : 9=DEXTER.1.19=13213035=X49=PARFX56=c3_user134=847352=20130408-22:27:59.611262=aquru2D00000002268=1509279=2269=055=EUR/CHF270=27379.5271=01023=598336=3346=0273=22:27:23.084279=0269=055=EUR/CHF270=27396.49271=440000001023=414336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0848722=0279=2269=055=EUR/CHF270=27404.86271=01023=305336=3346=0273=22:27:23.085279=0269=055=EUR/CHF270=27374.86271=400000001023=668336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0858722=0279=2269=055=EUR/CHF270=27416.14271=01023=174336=3346=0273=22:27:23.085279=2269=055=EUR/CHF270=27411.65271=01023=233336=3346=0273=22:27:23.085279=0269=055=EUR/CHF270=27363.95271=440000001023=808336=3346=1273=22:27:23.0858722=0279=2269=055=EUR/CHF270=27408.47271=01023=262336=3346=0273=22:27:23.098279=0269=055=EUR/CHF270=27400.23271=410000001023=371336=3346=1273=22:27:23.098
```

Comment: Why not just use `String.indexOf` and `String.substring`?

Comment: these kind of text repeats about 20000 times in a text file.

Comment: what is the expected output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple regex that would do it:

`9=DEXTER((?s:.)*?)((?=9=DEXTER)|$)`

Basically capture a group `((?s:.)*?)` between a `9=DEXTER` OR  end of file (`$`)

```
String regex = "9=DEXTER((?s:.)*?)((?=9=DEXTER)|$)";
String text = "9=DEXTERHello9=DEXTERworld\nnewline9=DEXTERfoo9=DEXTERbar";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(":"+s);
}
```

output:

```
:Hello
:world
new line
:foo
:bar
```